# Angular intercepting http errors

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, interceptor

I want to intercept each request and error responses.

I already can intercept requests and set a token in the headers and I can intercept the responses to handle a refresh token.

However I can't find a way to intercept `HttpErrorResponse`.

I tried 2 methods. One with an explicit rxjs catchError and the other with some kind of callback:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = this.auth.getToken();
    if (authToken) {
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('accesstoken', authToken) });
    }
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          //handle refresh token
        }
        return event;
      },
      catchError((error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          console.log(error);
          return Observable.throw(error);
        }
      })));
  }
```

If I have an expired token, every request throws an HttpErrorResponse but this solution doesn't catch it.

[image]

This is returned by the service. No sign of the console.log() from the interceptor.

The service looks like this:

```
public getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
        .get<any>(url)
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
                return res;
            }),
            catchError((e): Observable<any> => {
                console.log(e);
                const res: any = {error: e};
                return of(res);
            })
        );
}
```

Then I tried with a "callback syntax":

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(
  map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      // refresh token
    }
    return event;
  }, (error: any) => {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }));
```

Same result as above. Nothing in the console.

I've seen people (https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a) register an ErrorHandler in the module but I haven't tried it yet.

How do I catch an HttpErrorResponse from my interceptor?

EDIT:

I've tried the ErrorHandler way but still couldn't get any log. Then I removed the `catchError` from my service and finally got something logged...

I'll try to see if this makes the interceptor work... Not fun if I have to remove all my catchError :(

I made a reproducible example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2jc9n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular has a hook for error handling (https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler).

You can create a service which implements the angular ErrorHandler and implements `handleError` method where you can log all errors. This error handler would log not just HttpErrorResponse but all errors, but you can filter out the ones you need.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    private static isHttpErrorResponse(error): error is HttpErrorResponse {
        return error instanceof HttpErrorResponse;
    }

    handleError(error: any): void {
        if (CustomErrorHandler.isHttpErrorResponse(error)) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, even with this my error is not getting caught... I removed the rxjs catchError from the service and I get a console log from the handler :(

Comment: yes, if you use this handler, you don't need the catchError in the service

Comment: That's a huge pain. I thought the interceptor or error handler would have the priority over this... :( Thanks Michal

Comment: I'm having the same issue. So can't the interceptor handle custom exceptions?