# Handling error with rxjs not compatible with interceptors

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs

Based on this question [Angular intercepting http errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136475/angular-intercepting-http-errors) that is resolved, I'm facing a huge philosophical issue.

All my services look like this:

```
public getSomething(): Observable<Something> {
    return this.http
        .get<Something>(url)
        .pipe(
            map(res => res.data),
            catchError((e): Observable<any> => of(e))
        );
}
```

If my authentication token is invalid / expired, the service catches the error.
I can call log out right there.

However, if I have a lot of services, I have to repeat this process that many times. Thus I need to configure an interceptor or a custom error handler.

Both are not triggered if I keep catchError in the services.

If I choose to stay DRY, I need to remove catchError. If I remove catchError, rxjs becomes practically useless (finalize, retry...etc.)

If I choose to keep catchError, I need to modify all of them to call some kind of global error handling function to stay somewhat DRY. But then I'm not using Angular like I should.

How do I handle this situation?

EDIT: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2jc9n

There's the ErrorHandler active, the Interceptor is commented in app.module.
If you remove catchError from the service, the ErrorHandler is triggered, otherwise catchError takes precedence.

Comment: `catchError` doesn't really catch errors, it simply keeps the stream going when an error happens, swapping the error for the returned value. And since the stream doesn't stop and you use `HttpClient`, I don't see why your interceptors woudn't trigger. Consider leaving a [mcve] of your issue to show the exact issue.

Comment: *"Both are not triggered if I keep catchError in the services"* - Can you explain this?

Comment: @trichetriche you have a stackblitz here https://angular-m2jc9n.stackblitz.io

Comment: @gyc could you give the link to the stackblitz and not the demo of it please ?

Comment: @trichetriche oh sorry: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2jc9n

Comment: I can use tap with the error callback syntax, it fixes the problem. Isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a shared interceptor, you have in angular the [HTTP_INTERCEPTOR](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor):

in your `module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: LoginInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

And the service `LoginInterceptor`:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        }, (err: any) => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            // DO here what you want
            // this.router.navigate(['login']);
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**An alternative** will be to use a **guard** on the top of your route.

Comment: Endeed, but with the `tap`method, no need for catchError.

Comment: If I use tap inside the service, the interceptor is triggered... that doesn't tell me why (and I still need to modify all my services) but it somewhat fixes my issue.