# Force an error with rxjs inside my test stubs

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs

I have service that looks like this

```
public getData(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http
        .get<Data>(url)
        .pipe(
            tap(res => res),
            (e: any) => e);
}
```

I cannot use the catchError operator ([Handling error with rxjs not compatible with interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137275/handling-error-with-rxjs-not-compatible-with-interceptors))

In the component I subscribe to it and it throws an error when necessary

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
  myProp = true;
}, (error) => {
  if (error.errorMessage === 'xxx') {
    myProp = false;
  }
});
```

To test this I created a stub (which used to work with catchError)

```
export class ServiceStub {
    public getData(): Observable<Data> {
        return of({errorMessage: 'some error'});
    }
}
```

This code is returned inside the subscribe as 'res' but not in the error callback of the subscribe.

I tried to `Throw new Error('some error')` but I need to return an object.

I also tried `throw({errorMessage: 'some error'})` but the test fails with

> [object Object] thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `throwError` operator. For more info, check the [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError)

Change your stub to this

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

export class ServiceStub {
    public getData(): Observable<Data> {
        return throwError({errorMessage: 'some error'});
    }
}
```

Or you can use `Observable` constructor as follows

```
getData() {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    observer.error({errorMessage: 'some error'});
  });
}
```